# subscriptions in graphql-yoga

Tags: graphql, graphql-yoga

In the [pubSub-section](https://the-guild.dev/graphql/yoga-server/docs/features/subscriptions#pubsub) of graphql-yoga doc, under the **randomNumber** of **Subscription** resolver(server.ts), what does the resolve function i.e `resolve: (payload) => payload` do? and what is **payload**?

Answer (score 0):

- ***resolve*** function helps you to perform certain *operations* on your ***payload***.
- ***payload*** is the object that you want to publish, which is provided as the *last argument* in the ***pubsub.publish*** method.

for.eg.

```
type Mutation {
    count(data: Int): Int!
}
type Subscription {
    count: Int!
}
const Mutation = {
    count: (parent, args, { pubsub }, info) => {
        pubsub.publish("count", {
            count: 1,
        });
        return 1;
    },
};

const Subscription = {
    count: {
        subscribe: (parent, args, { pubsub }, info) => {
            return pubsub.subscribe("count");
        },
        resolve: (payload) => payload.count * 2,
    },
};
```

**This** prints out the following to the subscriber:

```
{
  "data": {
    "count": 2
  }
}
```

**Without** the "resolve" function it would have printed out:

```
{
  "data": {
    "count": 1
  }
}
```